# unable to update the MariaDB upgrade to work

Tags: ubuntu, apt, mariadb

Have run apt update and apt upgrade and this are the errors for mariadb

```
Ign:1 http://mariadb.mirror.liquidtelecom.com/repo/10.4/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 mysql-common all 1:10.4.9+maria~bionic
Ign:2 http://mariadb.mirror.liquidtelecom.com/repo/10.4/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 mariadb-common all 1:10.4.9+maria~bionic
Ign:3 http://mariadb.mirror.liquidtelecom.com/repo/10.4/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 mariadb-server all 1:10.4.9+maria~bionic
Ign:4 http://mariadb.mirror.liquidtelecom.com/repo/10.4/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 galera-4 amd64 26.4.3-bionic
Ign:5 http://mariadb.mirror.liquidtelecom.com/repo/10.4/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 mariadb-backup amd64 1:10.4.9+maria~bionic
Ign:6 http://mariadb.mirror.liquidtelecom.com/repo/10.4/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libmariadb3 amd64 1:10.4.9+maria~bionic
Ign:7 http://mariadb.mirror.liquidtelecom.com/repo/10.4/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 mariadb-client-core-10.4 amd64 1:10.4.9+maria~bionic
Ign:8 http://mariadb.mirror.liquidtelecom.com/repo/10.4/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 mariadb-client-10.4 amd64 1:10.4.9+maria~bionic
Ign:9 http://mariadb.mirror.liquidtelecom.com/repo/10.4/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 mariadb-server-core-10.4 amd64 1:10.4.9+maria~bionic
Ign:10 http://mariadb.mirror.liquidtelecom.com/repo/10.4/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 mariadb-server-10.4 amd64 1:10.4.9+maria~bionic
Err:4 http://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb-10.4/repo/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 galera-4 amd64 26.4.3-bionic
  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.1 80]
Ign:1 http://mariadb.mirror.liquidtelecom.com/repo/10.4/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 mysql-common all 1:10.4.9+maria~bionic
Ign:2 http://mariadb.mirror.liquidtelecom.com/repo/10.4/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 mariadb-common all 1:10.4.9+maria~bionic
Err:5 http://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb-10.4/repo/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 mariadb-backup amd64 1:10.4.9+maria~bionic
  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.1 80]
Ign:3 http://mariadb.mirror.liquidtelecom.com/repo/10.4/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 mariadb-server all 1:10.4.9+maria~bionic
Err:6 http://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb-10.4/repo/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libmariadb3 amd64 1:10.4.9+maria~bionic
  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.1 80]
Ign:1 http://mariadb.mirror.liquidtelecom.com/repo/10.4/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 mysql-common all 1:10.4.9+maria~bionic
Err:7 http://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb-10.4/repo/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 mariadb-client-core-10.4 amd64 1:10.4.9+maria~bionic
  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.1 80]
Err:8 http://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb-10.4/repo/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 mariadb-client-10.4 amd64 1:10.4.9+maria~bionic
  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.1 80]
Ign:2 http://mariadb.mirror.liquidtelecom.com/repo/10.4/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 mariadb-common all 1:10.4.9+maria~bionic
Err:9 http://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb-10.4/repo/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 mariadb-server-core-10.4 amd64 1:10.4.9+maria~bionic
  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.1 80]
Ign:3 http://mariadb.mirror.liquidtelecom.com/repo/10.4/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 mariadb-server all 1:10.4.9+maria~bionic
Err:10 http://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb-10.4/repo/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 mariadb-server-10.4 amd64 1:10.4.9+maria~bionic
  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.1 80]
Err:1 http://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb-10.4/repo/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 mysql-common all 1:10.4.9+maria~bionic
  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.1 80]
Err:2 http://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb-10.4/repo/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 mariadb-common all 1:10.4.9+maria~bionic
  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.1 80]
Err:3 http://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb-10.4/repo/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 mariadb-server all 1:10.4.9+maria~bionic
  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.1 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb-10.4/repo/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mariadb-10.4/mysql-common_10.4.9+maria~bionic_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.1 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb-10.4/repo/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mariadb-10.4/mariadb-common_10.4.9+maria~bionic_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.1 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb-10.4/repo/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mariadb-10.4/mariadb-server_10.4.9+maria~bionic_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.1 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb-10.4/repo/ubuntu/pool/main/g/galera-4/galera-4_26.4.3-bionic_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.1 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb-10.4/repo/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mariadb-10.4/mariadb-backup_10.4.9+maria~bionic_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.1 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb-10.4/repo/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mariadb-10.4/libmariadb3_10.4.9+maria~bionic_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.1 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb-10.4/repo/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mariadb-10.4/mariadb-client-core-10.4_10.4.9+maria~bionic_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.1 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb-10.4/repo/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mariadb-10.4/mariadb-client-10.4_10.4.9+maria~bionic_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.1 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb-10.4/repo/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mariadb-10.4/mariadb-server-core-10.4_10.4.9+maria~bionic_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.1 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb-10.4/repo/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mariadb-10.4/mariadb-server-10.4_10.4.9+maria~bionic_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.1 80]
```

Comment: those versions doesn't exist in repo, may you added wrong repo check https://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb-10.4/repo/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mariadb-10.4/

Comment: i have the same problem on an plesk server. I haven't added it manually

Comment: Err:1 http://mirror.nodesdirect.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/debian stretch/main amd64 mysql-common all 10.2.28+maria~stretch
  404  Not Found [IP: 2604:4600::175c:5c5e 80]..etc.

Comment: So what is happening I'm following the iinstructiiion on the main mariadb page to install...looks like it is lookinig for 10.4.9 but 10.4.8 is only available.

Answer (score 0):

Nasty bug in 10.4.9 so it was pulled but the APT was never updated to reflect this.